# Android Studio run tab doesn't show where the problem is

Tags: android, kotlin

[image]

- no errors in codes
- The project opens in the emulator. shuts down while entering data.
- I look in the 'run' tab to find the faulty line but there is no information.
- I just updated Android Studio (2022.3.1.18). There was no such problem before.
- before updating, the run tab was showing all my actions in the emulator. It was also showing the code that caused the shutdown.
- I am new to writing code. please explain easily.

'run' tab doesn't show where the problem is

Comment: Check the logcat

Comment: Android doesn't log to the console output, only LogCat.

Comment: before updating, the run tab was showing all my actions in the emulator. It was also showing the code that caused the shutdown.

Comment: That was a change in a recent version of Android Studio (no longer showing the error in the run tab) - the run tab isn't as useful as it once was.

Comment: How can I see the wrong line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check the errors in the logcat tab. if there is an error while writting the code you will a red line under it.